# geom_bar : There are extra x-axis appear in my bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My data is follow the sequence:

```
   deptime .count

1      4.5   6285
2     14.5   5901
3     24.5   6002
4     34.5   5401
5     44.5   5080
6     54.5   4567
7    104.5   3162
8    114.5   2784
9    124.5   1950
10   134.5   1800
11   144.5   1630
12   154.5   1076
13   204.5    738
14   214.5    556
15   224.5    544
16   234.5    650
17   244.5    392
18   254.5    309
19   304.5    356
20   314.5    364
```

My ggplot code:

```
ggplot(pplot, aes(x=deptime, y=.count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill='#FF9966',width = 5) + labs(x="time", y="count")
```

[output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKKSP.png)

There are a gap between each 100. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank You

Comment: do the answer satisfies the question?